# Como eu faço para tirar os espaços apenas da ultima coluna da matriz?

Tags: c++, matriz, array-multidimensional, espaço-em-branco

Iai galera, então meu código já ta completo funcionando perfeitamente, mas na ultima coluna ela também dá um espaço, mas eu não quero que fique esse espaço lá, como eu faço pra retirá-lo? Deixando apenas os espaços entre os números.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int linhas=0, colunas=0, soma1=0, soma2=0, contador1=0, contador2=0;




int calcDiagonalPrinc(){

  int matriz[linhas][colunas];




  return soma1;
}

int calcDiagonalSec(){

  int matriz[linhas][colunas];


 return soma2;
}



int main() {

  scanf("%d", &linhas);
  scanf("%d", &colunas);

  int matriz[linhas][colunas];

  for(int i=0; i<linhas; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<colunas; j++){
      scanf("%d", &matriz[i][j]);
    }
  }
  printf("\nMatriz formada:\n");
  for(int i=0; i<linhas; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<colunas; j++){
      printf("%d ", matriz[i][j]);
      
    }
    printf("\n");
    }

if(linhas==colunas){
  for(int i=0; i<linhas; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<colunas; j++){
      if(i==j){
        soma1=soma1+matriz[i][j];}
      if(matriz[i][j]<0){
        contador1++;
      }else
        if(matriz[i][j]>0){
        contador2++;
      }
        
    }
  }

  for(int i=0; i<linhas; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<colunas; j++){
      if((i+j)==linhas-1){
        soma2=soma2+matriz[i][j];

        
      }
    }  
  }
  printf("A diagonal principal e secundaria tem valor(es) %d e %d respectivamente.\n", soma1, soma2);
  printf("A matriz possui %d numero(s) menor(es) que zero.\n", contador1);
  printf("A matriz possui %d numero(s) maior(es) que zero.\n", contador2);

}else
  printf("A diagonal principal e secundaria nao pode ser obtida.\n");



  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Inácio. Usa "%d\t " no printf que irá imprimeir o elemento da matriz formatada. Ele usa Tabulação, é uma opção simples mas de fácil formatação. Ele da um 'tab' ao invés de espaço. Se você usar espaço vai ter que se preocupar com outros aspectos de formatação como tamanho dos espaçamentos e dos elementos numéricos para poder tabular corretamente.

Comment: https://onlinegdb.com/Tptk8ZVOt    <<  Neste link tem o seu código. Apenas modifiquei os printf para ficar mais compreensível o que você está fazendo. Mesmo eu seja seu, deixe-o legível nas operações, se não fica complicado saber o que está gerando de input.

Comment: Mesmo eu usando tab, ele deixa um tab tbm na ultima coluna e eu nao quero isso, queria que nao tivesse nada depois dos ultimos numeros da coluna

Answer (score 0):

Presumindo que esteja falando deste trecho:

```
  printf("\nMatriz formada:\n");
  for(int i=0; i<linhas; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<colunas; j++){
      printf("%d ", matriz[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
```

você pode fazer:

```
  printf("\nMatriz formada:\n");
  for(int i=0; i<linhas; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<colunas; j++){
      printf("%d%s", matriz[i][j], (j<colunas-1) ? " " : "");
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
```

Note que você poderia fazer:

```
printf("%d%s", matriz[i][j], (j<colunas-1) ? " " : "\n");
```

e eliminar o `printf("\n");`.